# Python lists, .txt files

Tags: python, list, text

I'm a beginner and I have a few questions. I have a .txt file with names + grades, for example:

```
Emily Burgess 5 4 3 4
James Cook 4 9 5 4
Blergh Blargh 10 7 2 4
```

I need to write their names, last names and the average of their grades in a new .txt file. Then I need to calculate all of theirs average grade. How do I do that? I have started doing this, but I don't know what to do now:

```
def stuff():
    things = []
    file = open(r'stuff2.txt').read()
    for line in file:
        things.append(line.split(' '))
    print(things)

    for grade in things:
        grades = int(grade[2], grade[3], grade[4], grade[5])
        average = grades/4
        print(average)

with open('newstuff.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(things)
```

Comment: You should really try to form habits where you think carefully about what something does or is when you name it. It may be because you're just messing around, but even in this short example, I must ask myself many times, "What does _stuff_ do again? And what is _things_ referring to?"

Comment: Are you calling the function? What is working as expected, where does it diverge from what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell, but it looks like you've got some problems in your `for` loop. For instance, you can't call the `int` constructor with 4 arguments:

```
TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)
```

Did you mean:

```
grades = [int(g) for g in grades[1:]]
average = sum(grades) / len(grades[1:])
```

instead?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: since you're a beginning Python student, we'll leave object oriented programming out of it for now, but I'll keep the code below in case you feel like exploring a little!

```
students = list() # initialize an accumulator list

with open("stuff2.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        data = line.strip().split(" ")
        # strip removes ending and beginning whitespace e.g. the ending \n and etc
        datadict = {}
        datadict['first'] = data[0]
        datadict['last'] = data[1]
        datadict['grades'] = data[2:]
        students.append(datadict)
        # this can all be done in one line, but it's much clearer this way
# after this, all your students are in `students`, each entry in `students` is a
# dictionary with keys `first`, `last`, and `grades`.

# OUTPUT
with open("newstuff.txt","w") as outfile:
    for student in students:
        outputline = ""
        outputline += student['first']
        outputline += " "
        outputline += student['last']
        outputline += ": "
        outputline += ", ".join(student['grades'])
        # ", ".join(list) gives you a string with every element of list
        # separated by a comma and a space, e.g. ','.join(["1","2","3"]) == "1, 2, 3"
        outputline += "|| average: "
        average = str(sum(map(int,student['grades']))/len(student['grades']))
        # since student['grades'] is a list of strings, and we need to add them, you
        # have to use map(int, student['grades']) to get their int representations.
        # this is equivalent to [int(grade) for grade in student['grades']]
        outputline += average
        outputline += "\n"

        outfile.write(outputline)

        # again, this can be done in one line
        # outfile.write("{0['first']} {0['last']}: {1}||{2}\n".format(
        #              student, ', '.join(student['grades']), sum(map(int,student['grades']))/len(student['grades']))
        # but, again, this is long and unwieldy.
```

I'm always a proponent of using classes for these kinds of applications

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self,name=None,grades=None,initarray=None):
        """Can be initialized as Student(name="Name",grades=[1,2,3]) or
Student(["First","Last",1,2,3])"""
        if not (name and grades) or (initarray):
            raise ValueError("You must supply both name and grades, or initarray")
        if (name and grades):
            self.name = name
            self.grades = grades
        else:
            self.name = ' '.join(initarray[:2])
            self.grades = initarray[2:]

    @property
    def average(self):
        return sum(self.grades)/len(self.grades)
```

Then you can do something like:

```
students = list()

with open(r"stuff2.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in file:
        students.append(Student(line.strip().split(" ")))
# students is now a list of Student objects
```

And you can write them all out to a file with:

```
with open("students_grades.txt","w") as out_:
    for student in students:
        out_.write(r"{student.name}: {45:grades}||{student.average}\n".format(
                  student=student, grades = ', '.join(student.grades)))
```

Though you'll probably want to pickle your objects if you want to use them later.

```
import pickle

with open("testpickle.pkl","wb") as pkl:
    pickle.dump(students,pkl)
```

Then use them again with

```
import pickle # if you haven't already, obviously

with open('testpickle.pkl','rb') as pkl:
    students = pickle.load(pkl)
```

Comment: "Since you're a beginning Python student... leave out the object-oriented." Interesting decision, but OO is a first-year university topic, and Python is OO through and through. +1 to your first answer.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I know I certainly didn't take any CS courses at university -- hell, I'm a MUSIC major! My Python tutorials didn't include OO until FAR after where OP seems to be experience-wise. I left in the OO solution because it's a better solution, but it doesn't do anyone any good to study solutions they can't grasp yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be made to work as thus:

```
 with open('stuff2.txt') as f1, open('newstuff.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for line in f:
        raw_data = line.rstrip().split()
        average = sum(int(i) for i in raw_data[2:])
        new_data = ' '.join(raw_data[:2] + [str(average)])
        f2.write(new_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original txt file is stuff2.txt, and you want the output in newstuff.txt:

```
def process_line(line):
    line = line.split()
    first = line[0]
    last = line[1]
    grades = [int(x) for x in line[2:]]
    average = sum(grades) / float(len(grades))
    return first, last, average

with open('stuff2.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open('newstuff.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        first, last, avg = process_line(line)
        f.write(first + " " + last + " " + str(avg) + "\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("stuff.txt", sep=" ", header=None, names=["first","last","grade1","grade2","grade3","grade4"])
df["average"] = (df["grade1"]+df["grade2"]+df["grade3"]+df["grade4"])/4.0
df.to_csv("newstuff.txt",sep=" ", index=False) #will print a header row, which you can disable with header=None
```